# Getting too many arguments in call to spdy.NewRoundTripperWithProxy error when i try to run my terratest go code for validating EKS cluster on AWS

Tags: go, terraform, terragrunt, golang-migrate, terratest

Getting too many arguments in call to spdy.NewRoundTripperWithProxy error when i try to run my terratest go code which deploys, validates and un-deploys k8s pod to/from AWS EKS

My scripts were perfectly working fine 3 months back but looks like some library change happened in between these 3 months in k8s side which is affecting my scripts

Most problematic part is i am unable to find out at which line number my script is failing

go mod init and go go mod tidy are working fine but as soon as i run go test command getting the error as attached in the screen shot.

[image]

My code is present in [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cquddgwdo7juhc2/ig-data-loader.go?dl=0)

Comment: Please let me know if anyone knows answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got resolution from gruntwork community which helped me to fix this issue

We need to call or use **go get -u k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.20.6** command which pulls/sets required library to relevant version

Below steps are the resolutions for the current problem

1. go mod init
2. go get -u k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.20.6
3. go mod tidy -compat=1.17
4. go test -v -timeout 120m | tee test_output.log